# tensorflow object detection: The RFCN module's MAP@0.5 is quite low

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I use tensorflow object detection api (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to train a rfcn model, using voc 2007+2012 trainval datasets, and tested on voc 2007 test. The MAP@0.5 is much lower compared to the caffe version. The caffe version are trained 110000 iterations, and the tensorflow version are trained to 140000 iterations. A pretrained resnet-v1-50 module to initialize the backbone feature extractor. The config file as follows:

```
#pascal_voc_resnet50_rfcn.config:
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 20
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet50'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0005
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 1.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      rfcn_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          op: CONV
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0005
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
            }
          }
        }
        crop_height: 18
        crop_width: 18
        num_spatial_bins_height: 3
        num_spatial_bins_width: 3
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.7
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 1.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.001
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .001
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .0001
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .00001
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "resnet_v1_50/resnet_v1_50.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: false
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 1500000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "voc_dataset/trainval.tfrecords"
  }
  label_map_path: "object_detection/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
#  num_examples: 8000
  num_examples: 4952
  num_visualizations: 4952
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 1
  visualization_export_dir: 'outputs_eval_imgs'
  metrics_set: 'pascal_voc_metrics'
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "voc_dataset/test.tfrecords"
  }
  label_map_path: "object_detection/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  num_epochs: 1
}
```

final result is:
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/aeroplane: 0.701776
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bicycle: 0.742742
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bird: 0.723409
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/boat: 0.513328
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bottle: 0.531051
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bus: 0.769170
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/car: 0.811411
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/cat: 0.831349
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/chair: 0.472102
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/cow: 0.790175
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/diningtable: 0.483809
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/dog: 0.819959
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/horse: 0.838640
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/motorbike: 0.733901
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/person: 0.765344
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/pottedplant: 0.379224
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/sheep: 0.719418
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/sofa: 0.576437
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/train: 0.726485
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/tvmonitor: 0.683094
PascalBoxes_Precision/mAP@0.5IOU: 0.680641

However, when I use the original version(based on caffe), the mAP is 0.746, and the detail is following:
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/aeroplane:   0.781
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bicycle:0.793
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bird: 0.756
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/boat:0.652
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bottle:0.578
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/bus:0.843
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/car:0.846
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/cat: 0.889
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/chair:0.565
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/cow:0.835
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/diningtable: 0.658
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/dog: 0.867
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/horse:0.857
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/motorbike:0.792
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/person:0.778
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/pottedplant:0.412
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/sheep: 0.757
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/sofa:0.723
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/train:0.846
PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/tvmonitor:0.684
PascalBoxes_Precision/mAP@0.5IOU: 0.746